# Use env var in the path section of LoadCredential of systemd unit file

Tags: systemd, environment-variables

I am creating a service that I want to run under Ubuntu using systemd. For this service I need to load a credential using the [`LoadCredential=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#LoadCredential=ID:PATH) option of systemd. This works with the following unit file options:

```
[Service]
LoadCredential=clientkey:/etc/test/test.key
ExecStart=/home/user/test.sh
```

Now I would like to specify the location of the key file as an environment variable, which I load through the [`EnvironmentFile=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#EnvironmentFile=) option. Reading the documentation of the `EnvironmentFile=` option it says that the environment variables are also available to use in the unit file. So my understanding is that the following should work:

```
# .conf file
CLIENT_KEY_FILE=/etc/test/test.key

# .unit file
[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=/etc/test/test.conf
LoadCredential=clientkey:${CLIENT_KEY_FILE}
ExecStart=/home/user/test.sh
```

But this does not work. Trying to read the `clientkey` credential I get `No such file or directory`.

Am I doing something wrong in my unit file or am I misreading the documentation?

Comment: The documentation is not always correct or easy to understand. In any case, I would interpret it as `Sets environment variables for executed processes`, so only to the e.g. `ExecStart` and not available on the unit.